# Request retries 2 times on 503 status despite an adapter with default 0 retries used

Tags: python, python-requests

There's a code that users requests session to send the request. It also mounts an HTTPAdapter with a default number of retries, which should be 0. However, I've noticed that sometimes on a 503 response there are 2 retries happening. I went through the relevant requests and urllib3 code, but couldn't find where this can be configured. I also tried to enable debug logs, but didn't get any relevant logs. In particular, Retry should output a log when it does a successful increment, but that didn't happen. I had an idea that maybe redirects can cause more requests, however all requests went to the same host and 503 doesn't seem like a code which comes with redirect. Can you help identifying why those retries can be happening, please?

requests version: 2.31.0.
urllib3 version: 1.26.16.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you making a request to a server that YOU wrote, or is it an outside server?  A 503 generally means the server is down, or a network interruption.

Comment: It's an internal service written by somebody else. Based on the Datadog tracing, the request reaches the service and is executed, but still returns 503. I think the logic to do that if there's a bad nonce sent with the request and it needs to be regenerated before the retry. Maybe there's a misuse of 503 actually. I've updated the question a bit.

Comment: If the server is behind an HTTP server, then there should be a log that might include the reason for the 503 -- a PHP error, or something like that.

Comment: In this case I think I know what the issue is - outdated nonce. I just need to update it before doing a retry. But I’m trying to figure out why requests does a retry 2 times despite seemingly not configured to do so.